# add javascripts and css files dynamicly to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, widget, append

I am building a javascript widget and i need to add my widget css and js files dynamicly to the client page.

I am doing this for now:

```
    var css = document.createElement('link');
   css.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
   css.setAttribute('href', 'css path');
   document.getElementById('test').appendChild(css);
   alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
```

But it does not add the element to the dom.
The alert shows correctly.

What i am missing?

EDIT1:

Here is the updated code: (note that this is only a test page).

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">
            test
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">


    var css = document.createElement('link');
    css.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    css.setAttribute('href', 'path');
    var header  = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    header.appendChild(css);
    alert(header.innerHTML);

        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

header.InnerHtml appears correct but nothing is added to the page.

Comment: Are you actually setting `href` to `"css path"`, or are you setting to the actual path to your CSS? - Also, append the CSS to the `<head>`.

Comment: The path is correct. I have pasted the url in the browser and it shows my css file.

Comment: the path is correct, but permissions on file css are right? if you insert straight to the document the file is correctly parsed?

Comment: Well it seems there was a little mistake in the path. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried to append the css into the <head> section ?

```
var css = document.createElement('link');
   css.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
   css.setAttribute('href', 'css path');
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
```

Comment: +1 - CSS includes need to be declared in the "head" element of the document. It isn't valid to include it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to attach it to the  of your html, not simply the document:

```
var css = document.createElement('link');
css.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
css.setAttribute('href', 'css path');
var header   = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
header.appendChild(css);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It still doesn´t work. The innerHTML of the header element is correct but nothing is added to the page. I will post the updated code at first post.